# How to run a shell script without terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, python, scripts

I have a shell command that executes a command and sends it through pipe to a python file. The python file does various checks on it and then starts processes with parameters using subprocess.Popen. But I see that it only works when I run the entire thing in a shell. Is there another way for me to execute it other than shell. If I just run it without any shell or use & to keep it at background, the processes started by python are named defunct in the ps -e table. Can someone help?

EDIT:

Here is run.sh, which I run :

```
#!/bin/bash
padsp julius -input mic -C $HOME/project/julius-grammer/julian.jconf | python -u $HOME/project/pythonControls/getcommand.py
```

However not all subprocess.popen fail to run. For example, if I use festival program, it runs. However xbacklight doesn't.

this is getcommand.py:

I removed the unnecessary part, and this the one that is necessary, com is string, I know this selection is going on fine.:

```
if(com == "COMPLETE BRIGHTNESS"):
    userin = Data(["xbacklight", "-set", "100"],"Maximum brightness")
    userin.interact()
if(com == "HALF BRIGHTNESS"):
    userin = Data(["/usr/bin/xbacklight", "-set", "50"],"Partial brightness")
    userin.interact()
if(com == "ZERO BRIGHTNESS"):
    userin = Data(["/usr/bin/xbacklight","-set", "0"],"Minimal brightness")
    userin.interact()
```

Now coming to the objects, this is how the class goes:

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, com="", msg="", sp="False"):
        self.command = com
        self.message = msg
        self.speak = sp
    def interact(self):
        if self.command != "":
            co = subprocess.Popen(self.command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            co.wait()
        if self.speak == True:
            self.say(self.message)
        else:
            subprocess.Popen(["notify-send","SysSec", self.message])
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Posting the code you're using would help us to help you.

Comment: @JorgeSuárezdeLis I updated the code. Please have a look.

Comment: could you also post your python code? Try to remove unnecessary bits of code.

Comment: @JorgeSuárezdeLis I have updated the rest of the code too. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you run a script without a console, you're doing it with the graphical session environment.

Create a file named `testenv.sh` with these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
env > ~/testenv.txt
```

Put the file on the same directory as your script. Run it from the graphical session. Open the file, save it elsewhere. Then run the file from a terminal and compare the output.

Chances are that the problem here is the `PWD`. You're relying on the script being run on the same directory where you are, but all the scripts run with the graphical session environment, are run with the `PWD` set at your home directory.

It might also be a problem with your script lacking a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).